# Cloning USB drive in VMware with partclone

Tags: arch-linux, partition, usb-drive, vmware, cloning

I created a virtual machine in VMware as follows:

1. SCSI HDD 1 GB   (Main for short)
2. SCSI HDD 0.8 GB (UClone for short)
3. SCSI HDD 4 GB  as a physically plugged UFD (Uphys for short)
4. Arch Linux ISO as virtual CD

Where the UFD is a live USB created with [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator).

After booting Arch via the ISO with `fdisl -l`, I get this mapping:

1. Main is sda
2. UClone is sdb
3. Uphys is sdc and is reported as W95 FAT32 (LBA).

Now I want to clone Uphys to UClone, note that Uphys used space is about 600 Mega. 
If I issue:

```
partclone.fat32 -b -s /dev/sdc -o /dev/sdb
```

I get:

```
fatclone.c: Unknown fat type!!
```

Is it referred to source or output? The former is reported as W95 FAT32, the latter is unallocated.

UPDATE

With `/dev/sdc1` as source, instead of `/dev/sdc`, I can go a bit further. But it seems that `partclone` is unable to get the actual used block size: 
http://s24.postimg.org/vwzhkhzcl/partclone1.png

If I set the `-C` option as suggested, I get a `clone seek error`  and the destination device gets messed:
http://postimg.org/image/51xaywn6r/

Answer (score 1):

I think yumi installs things to a partition, not to the entire disk, in which case it should not be /dev/sdc, but /dev/sdc1 should be your source? Likewise for the output. Take a look at the detailed fdisk -l /dev/sdc should make that clear. That is the only reason I can think of because otherwise your syntax is fine.

Comment: I updated the question based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As @johnshen64 said, you need to be copying to a partition as well as from a partition, not a device. If the destination partition were `sdb1`, then the command would be:

```
partclone.fat32 -b -s /dev/sdc1 -o /dev/sdb1
```

In the attached screenshot you only fixed half of the command.

Comment: Again `parclone` asks for the `-C` switch and again there is an error with it; but this time the partition doesn't look corrupted with `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. See http://postimg.org/image/nco4mkau1/

Comment: What is in `/var/log/partclone.log`?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/eszgc8onb/ Note: reexcuting  I see that the error triggers at about  98% completion.

Comment: Partclone clones the contents of the partition, not the partition itself. Allocate a fat32 partition on UClone, then use partclone.

Comment: I repartitioned the output partition `sdb1` (UClone) as W95 Fat32 following these steps: http://blog.jim80.net/2009/07/29/make-a-fat32-partition-in-linux/, but still I get the error:  http://postimg.org/image/428dvae8v/.

Comment: Maybe try resizing Uphys to the size of Uclone first. The contents of Uphys are probably not all in its first 0.8 GB and its sounds like `partclone` places the stuff into the same positions in the new partition (i.e. it leaves unused blocks between the used ones).

Comment: Uphys is a physical USB drive. How do I resize it? Do you mean resizing the partition, leaving unallocated free space?

Comment: Yes I meant the partition `sdc1`. Make `sdc1` and `sdb1` the same size, then run `partclone`.

Comment: Uphys is  partitioned and  formatted by YUMI as fat32. How can I resize it booting from the Arch ISO?

Comment: Just use `gparted`, its graphical and straightforward.

Comment: what if I try to copy the partition boot sector (maybe with `dd`) and then the files from sdc1 to sdb1? is it too difficult?

Comment: What is the end goal of this?

Comment: if I use `Yumi` to generate a new live USB, I will have to boot  again gparted and downsize the USB drive partition, then boot again in Arch to run partclone. Besides when I understand the method, I could create a script for cloning the live USB, test it, and cloning back from the virtual drive to the USB drive; `gparted` instead is just point and click.

Comment: I mean why do you want to copy the partition from Uphys to UClone? There is `parted` which is what `gparted` is a frontend for.

Comment: I read in parted manual that "after version 2.4, the following commands were removed: check, cp, mkfs, mkpartfs, move, resize.". So is it possible to manually copy files with `cp` and copy the partition bootsector with `dd` (or whatever)?

Comment: It could be possible, but I don't understand why you want to do this. What is your end goal?

Comment: My goal is to clone a USB flash drive into a virtual one, use it in the VM and then clone it back to the physical UFD. I'd like to use command line tools, which I can eventually call inside a script. As of now I have seen that: a) `partclone` is unable to clone the whole disk, b) when cloning partition to partition, `partclone` is unable to detect actual used blocks (which should be the main benefit of using `partclone`), c) I need `gparted` to resize the UFD, but that's not for CLI, d) `parted` is for CLI but unable to resize a partition. So I wonder if `dd` and `cp` are the best way to go.